# how to get the latitude and longitude without using gps in android?

Tags: android, gps

i know how to get the latitude and longitude values using gps system. Is it possible with out using gps system.

if possible Any one help me how to get the  latitude and longitude without using gps system?

actvity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener{
 private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 80;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 8000 * 60 * 1;
LocationManager mLocationManager;
Location  location;
Boolean isNetworkEnabled;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
if (isNetworkEnabled) {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
            if (mLocationManager != null) {
              Location  location = mLocationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (location != null) {
                 double   latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double  longitude = location.getLongitude();
                }
            }

}
}
```

error:cant resolve the method  "requestLocationUpdates"

Comment: my little knowledge.. it`s not possible without gps..what purpose for your qtn?

Answer (score 0):

use network provider instead

```
public class TestLocation extends FragmentActivity implements
        LocationListeners {

     private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 80;
     private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 8000 * 60 * 1;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                location = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                                if (location != null) {
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                }
                            }
                    }
}
```

Comment: where i need to write this? in oncreate? could you please declare locationManager and location variable?

Comment: yes and you need to implement LocationListener as well

Comment: with LocationListener

Comment: done but please if it help you accept the answer and please note that it's not good good to ask an open question without providing the knowledge you gain through search or a little code so people could help you

Comment: sorry @Ahmed. locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this); showing error to me. thats y asked.

Comment: No I was just telling you so your question doesn't get down voted that's all :)

Comment: requestLocationUpdates is a method implemented in location manager which means it's not an error please clean and build your code

Comment: i already cleaned and build. but it is showing error to me. no suitable method found for requestLocationUpdates

Comment: Please make sure that you are compiling with api above 9